# Round button in Android

Tags: android, layout, button, contacts

I want to create a circular button having a plus and minus sign on to this and exactly used in Android
Contacts application like shown in the image as below:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may see implementation of this button in android [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/froyo-release)

It's just ImageButton with circular png as background. Here is definition of their styles:

```
<style name="MinusButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_circle</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_btn_round_minus</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/description_minus_button</item>
</style>

<style name="PlusButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_circle</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_btn_round_plus</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/description_plus_button</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What if I had to show text on the button? I mean just like extending normal buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Just apply your image using `android:background="@drawable/image"` as one of the button properties in the xml file