# How to make a round button?

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to make a round button, but I don't know how can I do it. I can make button with rounded corners, but how can I can round circle. It's not the same. Please, tell me, is it possible on Android? Thank you.

Comment: have good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button

Comment: Google have new framework,
new technologies is better [Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round/64087445#64087445)

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Create an xml file named `roundedbutton.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Finally set that as background to your `Button` as `android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"`

If you want to make it completely rounded, alter the radius and settle for something that is ok for you.

Comment: Do you need the .xml suffix? I've seen an example without

Comment: @Neil you do not need to add xml suffix, I did it for the purpose of demonstration and clear understanding of the concept so that the reader doesn't take the example wrong, eclipse auto-assist should help you find if .xml is needed or not, I have a habit of using ctrl+space on my windows machine for auto completing xml commands.

Comment: You don't need an '@' symbol before the word drawable?

Comment: Does this solution have a different result than just using a round image as the background?

Comment: Also, why not use android:shape="oval"

Comment: How can I manage to make color dynamic in here? is there any way to chage color in roundedbutton.xml file?

Comment: You also can give 1 radius size for all corners
<corners android:radius="8dp"/>

Comment: It did not make button completely circular

Comment: Make radius 90dp to make fully round button

Answer (score 60):

If using Android Studio you can just use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    </shape>
```

this works fine for me, hope this helps someone.

Comment: that should be the accepted answer, using corners values doesn't go beyond rounded corners, and this question is about a circle. Thanks Shaun for this answer

Comment: Using `ring` doesn't show anything. Better to use `oval`.

Answer (score 36):

1. Create a drawable/button_states.xml file containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_pressed="false"> 
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
           <solid android:color="#41ba7a" />
           <stroke
               android:width="2dip"
               android:color="#03ae3c" />
           <padding
               android:bottom="4dp"
               android:left="4dp"
               android:right="4dp"
               android:top="4dp" />
           </shape>
       </item>
       <item android:state_pressed="true"> 
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
           <solid android:color="#3AA76D" />
           <stroke
               android:width="2dip"
               android:color="#03ae3c" />
           <padding
               android:bottom="4dp"
               android:left="4dp"
               android:right="4dp"
               android:top="4dp" />
           </shape>
       </item>
   </selector>
   ```
2. Use it in button tag in any layout file

   ```
   <Button
       android:layout_width="220dp"
       android:layout_height="220dp"
       android:background="@drawable/button_states"
       android:text="@string/btn_scan_qr"
       android:id="@+id/btn_scan_qr"
       android:textSize="15dp"
   />
   ```

Comment: its workng perfectly,thank you. can you help me to draw rectangle from center to outside of circle looks like a 'Q'

Comment: Working fine, but why did we put radius to 1000dp? can you please explain?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran 1000dp is an arbitrary size that's big enough to make the button round.

Comment: Is there an Android dimension resource that we can use instead of 1000dp ?

Answer (score 14):

**[Markushi's android circlebutton:](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton)**

(This library is deprecated and no new development is taking place. Consider using a FAB instead.)

[image]

Comment: warning: **DEPRECATED!**

Answer (score 13):

If you want a FAB looking circular button and you are using the official Material Component library you can easily do it like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
    app:cornerRadius="28dp"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="1" />
```

Result:

[image]

If you change the size of the button, just be careful to use half of the button size as `app:cornerRadius`.

Comment: How can we reduce the default padding of FAB? For me I can only see the first character of the text I put.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#ffffff"
    />
</shape>
```

Set that on your XML drawable resources, and simple use and image button with an round image, using your drawable as background.

Answer (score 7):

Update 2021:

Just use the **MaterialButton**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:cornerRadius="30dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="test" />
```

- width equal height
- cornerRadius is half of the width or height

Comment: u should give a complete answer....for those who are **facing a error** from the above code 

add this line `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'` to **build.gradle(:app)**

Answer (score 6):

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="180dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="180dip"
    android:topRightRadius="180dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="180dip"/>

<solid android:color="#6E6E6E"/> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
```

and add this to the button code

```
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Answer (score 5):

Used the shape as oval. This makes the button oval

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <stroke
            android:height="1.0dip"
            android:width="1.0dip"
            android:color="#ffee82ee" />

        <solid android:color="#ffee82ee" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="12.0dip"
            android:bottomRightRadius="12.0dip"
            android:radius="12.0dip"
            android:topLeftRadius="12.0dip"
            android:topRightRadius="12.0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `MaterialButton`:

```
     <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:text="A"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Rounded"
            />
```

and apply a circular `ShapeAppearanceOverlay` with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Round button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914329/round-button-in-android)

You can make a `ImageButton` with circular background image.

Answer (score 3):

use **ImageButton** instead of Button....

and make Round image with **transparent** background

Answer (score 2):

For a round button create a shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<stroke
    android:width="8dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<solid android:color="#ffee82ee" />


<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="45dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="45dp"
    android:topRightRadius="45dp" />
```

use it as a background of your button [link](http://www.pallandri.blogspot.com/2014/07/android-create-round-buttons.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, look for 9-patch on google. Good articles :

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/custom-color-buttons-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

You can use google's FloatingActionButton

XMl:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Java:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton bold = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    bold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do Stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Gradle:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply use a `FloatingActionButton` with `elevation = 0dp` to remove the shadow:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:elevation="0dp" />
```

Comment: problem of FAB is that it can not use transparent and full-color images, oly b/w vectors. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution

```
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                >
                <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
              android:src="@drawable/social_facebook"
                        />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
android.R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized
```

look into built in android drawables:

http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Image Buttons and make the background as the image you want.
2. Create the images from the android asset studio link -

" https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(94%2C%20126%2C%20142%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(96%2C%20125%2C%20139)&crop=1&backgroundShape=circle&effects=none&name=ic_home "

and download it, extraxt it , inside that look for mipmap-hdpi folder.

3. copy the image from the mipmap-hdpi folder and paste it in the drwable folder of your android project.
4. Now set the background as that image.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the answers. But none of them is beginner friendly. So here I have given a very detailed answers fully explained with pictures.

Open Android Studio. Go to **Project Window** and scroll to **drawable** folder under **res** folder

[image]

Right click, select **New** --> **drawable resource folder**

[image]

In the window that appears, name the file `rounded_corners` and click on **OK**

[image]

A new file `rounded_corners.xml` gets created

Open the file. You are presented with the following code -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

[image]

Replace it with the following code -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#66b3ff" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Here the design view can be seen on the right side

Adjust the value in `android:radius` to make the button more or less rounded.

Then go to `activity_main.xml`

Put the following code -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I have placed the `Button` inside a `RelativeLayout`. You can use any `Layout` you want.

For reference purpose `MainActivity.java` code is as follows -->

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have a **Pixel 4 API 30** **avd** installed.
After running the code in the **avd** the display is as follows -->

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Fully rounded circle shape.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#F0F0F0" />
    <corners
        android:radius="90dp"/>
</shape>
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs a floating action button, but doesn't want to depend on the entire material library, here's a minimal implementation that looks exactly the same, has ripple animation, the shadow, and `show()`/`hide()` methods with animation.

[image]

Widget code:

```
class CircularImageButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
) : AppCompatImageButton(context, attrs) {
    init {
        background = null
        outlineProvider = pillOutlineProvider
        clipToOutline = true
    }

    fun show() {
        if (visibility != VISIBLE) {
            visibility = VISIBLE
            startAnimation(showAnimation)
        }
    }

    fun hide() {
        if (visibility != INVISIBLE) {
            visibility = INVISIBLE
            startAnimation(hideAnimation)
        }
    }

    override fun setBackgroundColor(color: Int) {
        if (backgroundPaint.color != color) {
            backgroundPaint.color = color
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint().apply { style = Paint.Style.FILL }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawPaint(backgroundPaint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}


val pillOutlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
    override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.width, view.height, view.height.f / 2)
    }
}


private val animationDuration = applicationContext
        .resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime).toLong()

val showAnimation = ScaleAnimation(
        0f, 1f, 0f, 1f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)
        .apply { duration = animationDuration }

val hideAnimation = ScaleAnimation(
        1f, .5f, 1f, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)
        .apply { duration = animationDuration }
```

And the xml, where 40dp is the “mini” version of the FAB.

```xml
<CircularImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_your_drawable"
    android:scaleType="center"

    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"

    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#7000"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#7000"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
```

Answer (score 0):

With jetpack compose, you can customize your button without requiring any 3-party lib or boilerplate code.

```
  Button(
        onClick = { /* do something when button clicked*/ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(64.dp)
            .height(64.dp),
        shape = CircleShape
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Star, "")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't waste your time by creating drawable file, instead use below attributes in your material button

```
    app:cornerRadius="100dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#E6D4EFF0"
```