# I want to design login n sign up(register) page like shown in image pz give mi source code

Tags: android

Please give me code to design edit text box, button with round corners, etc. Which is shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear ? do you want round corner textview  or all of that design ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for answers already? I'm sure this question has been answered here before. Relevant examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266595/how-to-make-a-round-button

Comment: @behroz : i want tht full design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use xml drawable and use it as background

first go to drawable directory and create new Drawable Resource file and name it MyRoundButton then copy all this code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:color="#ff66cc"
    android:width="2dp"/>

<corners
    android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

then add this to your Button background

```
android:background="@drawable/MyRoundButton"
```

now you can change the corner radius by changing

> android:radius="someValue"

and border color by

> android:color="#someColor"