# How to create small round buttons that contains an icon at the centre?

Tags: android

I want to create buttons in my android application, just like shown in the image below

[image]

you can se all the four buttons below.

I want to give them a custom color background and then an icon on the top. There is no way I'm able to adjust the icon at the centre of button.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Here is the best library for the buttons - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6285

Comment: Android library is enough. Just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267166/5154891)

Comment: @ThomasMary I know how to create round buttons but I am not able to put an icon at the centre of the button with a colored background.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with FrameLayout and for circle background you need to create a shape drawable file. Refer my answer here.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**round_shape.xml** add this file in drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="@color/profile_grey"
        android:endColor="@color/profile_grey"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Drawable and use that drawable as Button Background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="#e1e1e1"
            android:width="0.5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

This Code create a circle with white background.

Comment: True that but putting an icon on the top of that background and that too in the middle is another story.

Comment: @YatendraRathore, Check my answer it may help for you

Comment: `<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:src="@drawable/img"
                android:padding="10dp"/>`

Try This.
Take Image View Instead of Button.