# Buttons in a circle

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imagebutton, geometry

[image: For the below circle can I create individual buttons on the same circle for each and every zodiac sign]

For the above circle can I create individual buttons on the same circle for each and every zodiac sign

Comment: Yes give background to button...

Comment: You can have a hint from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) of putting Buttons in collection makes a *circle*.

Comment: you can use imageButton and set a circle background to it

Comment: this link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914329/round-button-in-android

Comment: You can put that image as a linear layout and construct separate ButtonViews and spacing them out perfectly. However, this would be very buggy for multiple devices in which case you can choose to do some math and create the buttons through code and code it in a way in which the size will scale to the device size.

I'd recommend you to take a look at canvas and have a button class that way you have much more control over what appears on the screen and the device size and the dimensions of the buttons and background image.

Comment: may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222730/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control

Answer (score 1):

That image is probably way too complex to replicate with multiple views. The best thing you could do would probably be to just extend a `View` or `ImageView`, and then override the `onTouch` method.

In onTouch you can get the exact XY coordinates of the touch, and compare it with the known boundaries of all the individual clickable areas. Based on what area you click you can take a different action.